# Merging two dataframes with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

This is a subset of data frame 
F1:

```
id        code    s-code
l.1        1       11
l.2        2       12
l.3        3       13
f.1        4       NA
f.2        3        1
h.1        2        1
h.3        1        1
```

I need to compare the F1.id with F2.id and then add the differences in column "id" to the F2 data frame and fill in columns' values for the added "id" with 0.

this is the second data frame
F2:

```
id        head    sweat  pain
l.1        1       0      1
l.3        1       0      0
f.2        3        1     1
h.3        1        1     0
```

The output should be like this:

F3:

```
id        head    sweat  pain
l.1        1       0      1
l.3        3       13     0  
f.2        3        1     1
h.1        2        1     1
h.3        1        1     0
l.2        0        0     0
h.1        0        0     0
f.1        0        0     0
```

I tried different solution, such as 
    `F1[(F1.index.isin(F2.index)) & (F1.isin(F2))]` to return the differences, but non of them worked.

Comment: Check your expected output... there's a 13 in there. Is that a mistake?

Comment: How you got two h.1 ..in column Id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an outer `merge` + `fillna`:

```
df[['id']].merge(df2, how='outer')\
            .fillna(0).astype(df2.dtypes)

    id  head  sweat  pain
0  l.1     1      0     1
1  l.2     0      0     0
2  l.3     1      0     0
3  f.1     0      0     0
4  f.2     3      1     1
5  h.1     0      0     0
6  h.3     1      1     0
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED, Thank you. Is there anyway not to mention the name of columns from df2? I have about 40 columns in df2.

Comment: `astype(df2.dtypes)`

Comment: piRSquared, Wonderful. I didn't know you could do that. @Mary, you have your answer.

Answer (score 4):

By using `reindex`

```
df2.set_index('id').reindex(df1.id).fillna(0).reset_index()
Out[371]: 
    id  head  sweat  pain
0  l.1   1.0    0.0   1.0
1  l.2   0.0    0.0   0.0
2  l.3   1.0    0.0   0.0
3  f.1   0.0    0.0   0.0
4  f.2   3.0    1.0   1.0
5  h.1   0.0    0.0   0.0
6  h.3   1.0    1.0   0.0
```

Comment: Very nice. You can shorten this: `df2.set_index('id').reindex(df['id'], fill_value=0).reset_index()` - bonus: you get int columns, so no need to convert.

Comment: It also preserves the dtypes

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes you are right :) much nicer! BTW ...I do not think I get the expected out put he want ....

Comment: It's the same as mine though? OP seemed to approve of it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Base on his description , ours solution should be ok, but if you look at his expected out put ....

Comment: I know, I think there was a mistake when writing it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that is make sense .. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Outside the Box**

```
i = np.setdiff1d(F1.id, F2.id)
F2.append(pd.DataFrame(0, range(len(i)), F2.columns).assign(id=i))

    id  head  sweat  pain
0  l.1     1      0     1
1  l.3     1      0     0
2  f.2     3      1     1
3  h.3     1      1     0
0  f.1     0      0     0
1  h.1     0      0     0
2  l.2     0      0     0
```

---

With a normal index

```
i = np.setdiff1d(F1.id, F2.id)
F2.append(
    pd.DataFrame(0, range(len(i)), F2.columns).assign(id=i),
    ignore_index=True
)

    id  head  sweat  pain
0  l.1     1      0     1
1  l.3     1      0     0
2  f.2     3      1     1
3  h.3     1      1     0
4  f.1     0      0     0
5  h.1     0      0     0
6  l.2     0      0     0
```